# Complex expressions for venn diagrams A, B and C

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So there are cases of venn diagrams with sets A, B and C that are a little bit tougher than usual. I will post some examples here that are exercises for practice for my exam and my attempts at them. The task is to write the correct expression for the sets A,B and C for each venn diagram.

[exercise 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ5vV.png)

So, what's obvious is that we have A ∩ B ∩ C (which is in the middle). Then there is a part of A left which I think: A ⋃ Bc ⋃ Cc. So all together, this is (A ∩ B ∩ C) ∪ (A ⋃ Bc ⋃ Cc)? I'm not sure if this is right though, please correct me if I'm wrong.

[exercise 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AISK.png)

This one feels a little more straight forward. (A ⋃ B ⋃ C) - (A ⋂ B ⋂ C). Again, not sure that I expressed it right.

[exercise 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgVt5.png)

(A ⋂ B) ⋃ (B ⋂ C) ⋃ (A ⋂ C) - (A ⋂ B ⋂ C)

[exercise 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMnSE.png)

(A ⋂ C) U (B-A) U (B-C) ?

Like I said, I don't know if I'm right on any of these exercises, there is no hindsight, so please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. In general, when these more complex expressions for venn diagrams come, is there any general strategy that can make it easier? Like maybe drawing all the sets separately and then combining them or something?

Comment: The general strategy is find the expressions of each parts first, then combine them together with $\cup$.

exercise $1$:

$$(A\cap B^c\cap C^c)\cup(A\cap B\cap C)$$

exercise $2$:

$$(A\cap B^c\cap C^c)\cup(A^c\cap B\cap C^c)\cup(A^c\cap B^c\cap C)\cup(A\cap B\cap C)$$

exercise $3$:

$$((A\cap B)\cup(B\cap C)\cup(A\cap C))\cap(A\cap B\cap C)^c$$

exercise $4$:

$$(B\cap A^c\cap C^c)\cup(A\cap C\cap(A\cap B\cap C)^c)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that Venn diagrams can be used in two different ways: we can use a Venn diagram to indicate/highlight some specific set, but we can also use Venn diagrams to make a claim about certain sets. For example, take the following diagram:

[image]

The first usage of Venn diagrams is to say: "Look at the shaded region:  *That* is what we mean by the intersection of $A$ and $B$, i.e. $A \cap B$"

The second usage, however, interprets Venn diagrams as making a *claim* about these sets. In particular, a shaded area is interpreted as the claim that that area is empty.  So, the above diagram would be interpreted as "The intersection of $A$ and $B$ is empty", i.e. as the claim $A \cap B = \emptyset$

So, the first question you have to ask yourself is:  how are the given Venn Diagrams supposed to be used?  Are you supposed to find an expression that indicates the shaded areas? Or are you supposed to represent a claim about those areas?

I am suspecting it is the former ... in which case see Manx's Answer. But this is something you may want to check!

Also, if you do use Venn diagrams in the first way, and if you have symmetric difference available to you, then there is a nice expression for the second one:

$$A \triangle B \triangle C$$

Why does that work?  It's because $\triangle$ is the set-theoretic counterpart of the logical $XOR$, and the generalized $XOR$ is true iff an odd number of its terms are true.  And in your second diagram, you want to pick out exactly those regions that include an odd number of the sets.

Comment: Thank you. Just a follow up question though, is A ⊕ B the same as A △ B? I mean different symbols but same meaning?

Comment: @JeanDoe $\oplus$ is a truth-functional operator, while $\triangle$ is a set-theoretic operator, so they are really different animals ... but yes, they are isomorph to each other in the same way that the truth-functional $\land$ is isomorph to the set-theoretic $\cap$. Also, for any two sets $A$ and $B$ you can define $A \triangle B = \{ x | x \in A \oplus x \in B \}$